# input file isn't being read correctly scripting awk

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, awk

Hi I have two input files.

input1.txt:

```
id above
id below
id still
id getting
```

input2.txt

```
id above
value above the sky

id below
value under the chair
```

im trying to do an awk command and it shows up empty.

```
 awk -f find.awk input1.txt input2.txt
```

I know my awk works because im inputting 2 different txt files and all the outputs are correct and visible.

the difference between the different input2.txt files is...

when i go to use notepad on a windows machine the whole file turns out to be one string, while if you use any txt editor, it's formatted with separate lines.

example input2.txt on notepad.

```
  id above value above the sky id below value under the chair
```

I can't just reparse this input by id, because my real txt file has more data ... which is inconsistent so i can't just search for a string or reg expression.

find.awk

```
 FNR==NR  { id[$0]; next }  
 $0 in id { f=1 }           
 f                          
 NF==0    { f=0 }
```

and idea on why my awk isn't working?

Comment: updated the description with find.awk

Comment: are you creating the input files in Windows and sending them to UNIX/Linux with carriage returns?

Comment: hnm. no? should i be doing so? the txt file was given to me. im trying to parse it. im not sure why the previous person used.

Comment: so im using msk toolkit on windows.

Comment: no, you shouldn't be -- i was asking because i thought that DOS carriage returns could be causing the one line concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Run "dos2unix" on your input files before running awk on them. man dos2unix.

Comment: I hear there's this thing called "the interweb" or something that some people are finding useful for looking up information...